# How to i show dropdown list in flutter from mysql in my android Phone?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dropdown

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu where it will display data from mysql table in Flutter.

here is my code:

var selectedValue;

List categoryItemList = [];

Future getAllCategory() async {

```
var url = Uri.parse("http://localhost/dropdown_pratice/select.php");

var response = await http.get(url);


if (response.statusCode == 200) {

  var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

  setState(() {

    categoryItemList = jsonData;

  });

}

print(categoryItemList);
```

}

@override

void initState() {

```
super.initState();

getAllCategory();
```

}

Dropdown:

```
 DecoratedBox(

          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 200),
            child: DropdownButton(
                isExpanded: true,
                hint: Text("Select Customer's Name"),
                value: selectedValue,
                items: categoryItemList.map((master) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: master['name'], child: Text(master['name']));
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedValue = value;
                    debtor_no.text = selectedValue;
                  });
                }),
          )),
```

This code is working on localhost, but i have to run this code on android phone. This code is not working on android phone. i have also checked by replacing the localhost with my laptop ip and my mobile phone ip but still not working. Can any one help me?

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://medium.com/@podcoder/connecting-flutter-application-to-localhost-a1022df63130) can help you.

Comment: https://github.com/DaymaManish/flutter_sqflite_crud/blob/main/lib/homepage.dart

Answer (score 0):

the issue isn't in your code. it's related with url link that you try to use. you're trying to access to your local server by your real device but if you want to try it on the simulator will work correctly.
So you should upload your database on any real host and there are a lot of free options like ( [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com/) , [infinityfree](https://www.infinityfree.net/) ....etc ) or using a tool that allow to connect your device with localhost like this [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)